# Terminating Query If Not Connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, vba

I have a code that uploads data to a SQL server database, I am trying to add in an IF line of code saying if there is a connection then to continue, but if there is not a connection then to END. I am having a difficult time figuring out the wording and placement though. The beginning of the code that connects is:

```
Public Function Update()
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef

Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Dim err As DAO.Error

Const ConnectionString = _
        "ODBC;" & _
            "Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};" & _
            "Server=SERV;" & _
            "Database=DB;" & _
            "UID=ID;" & _
            "PWD=PWD;"
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("")

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("CDData", dbOpenTable)

qdf.Connect = ConnectionString

Do While Not rs.EOF
```

Comment: So now you realize that you could have saved all this coding and used a linked table. So now you are back to square one and having to test for a legitimate connection BEFORE you run your code or my suggested idea of a append query + a linked table. I have a good answer but I first need to know why you are using a bunch of code that could be eliminated by using a simple linked table. So unless you explain why you are running up billable hours for no good reason other then theft of company resources then I have to figure out if I wasting my time giving advice to you?

Comment: Because I initially did have a linked table, but the powers that be decided that they do not want it that way, and told me they wanted it done this way.

Comment: Ok, as long as they are paying for this extra work and thus they wasting their time and thus the wasted developer time is their fault? As long as you informed them as such that they are increasing developer costs then I shall post my answer. However you do realize that you have a duty to inform them that less costly approaches exist.

Comment: By the way, if you not using linked tables then why this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22055684/linking-to-sql-server-database-from-ms-access-using-linked-tables

Comment: That wasn't a question I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While one can simple attempt to execute any query or command, the “time out” and delay to test for an active connection can result in a VERY LONG delay. As a result a wonderful trick exists that uses a DIFFERENT connection mechanism in Access and thus “reduces” the potential VERY long delay when attempting to use a saved query that is based on linked tables. (that "different" connection system occurs when you create a queryDef as opposed to a linked table or a query based on a linked table to sql server)

The follow code will return true or false if you have a working SQL connection:

```
Function TestLogin(strcon As String) As Boolean

  On Error GoTo TestError

  Dim dbs          As DAO.Database
  Dim qdf          As DAO.QueryDef

  Set dbs = CurrentDb()
  Set qdf = dbs.CreateQueryDef("")

   qdf.Connect = strcon

   qdf.ReturnsRecords = False

   'Any VALID SQL statement that runs on server will work below.

   qdf.SQL = "SELECT 1 as test"
   qdf.Execute

   TestLogin = True

   Exit Function

TestError:
   TestLogin = False
   Exit Function
```

End Function

So in code you now with your connection string code go:

```
If TestLogIn(strConn) = false then
    msgbox "no connection or logon invalid"
    exit sub
End If

' record processing code goes here for successful logon/connection.
```

Comment: I already have a test connection in the beginning, its during this upload process I need the connection check.